# Android Studio: worker class for upload data to firebase

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, android-workmanager

I am looking for a solution for uploading data to Firebase without having the user wait for the data to upload, so that the user can use the app in offline mode.

Let's suppose that the app is about *places*. In this app, the user can upload an image and an object containing address, city, state, country, latitude, longitude, description, etc. Let's say a big POJO.

Firebase Realtime Database and Firebase Firestore can wait for (I do not know for how long) a stable internet connection to send the data. But Firebase Storage do not have this feature.

So I've found `WorkManager`. It seemed to solve the problem, but I had to serialize my POJO into small primitive variable types in order to send the POJO to `Worker` class.

The result I want to achieve is:

1) upload image to Firebase Storage

2) download URL of the image

3) send the POJO to Firebase Firestore with the ImageUrl in it.

**QUESTIONS**

1) Is `WorkManager` best suited for this kind of purpose?

2) How many times can an user trigger this background job without causing any issue to the app in offline mode?

3) How to propperly send the POJO to the `Worker` class?

Here is what I've done so far:

Get pushKey for the new place, start the background job and keep navigating through activities:

```
    savePlaceData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            DocumentReference docRef = DatabaseRouter.getPlaceCollectionRef().document();
            String key = docRef.getId();
            uploadPlaceDataInBackground(key)
            Intent intent = new Intent(PlaceActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Set the request for the background job:

```
    private void uploadPlaceDataInBackground(String placeKey) {
        // TESTING WORKMANAGER FOR UPLOADING IMAGES TO FIREBASE STORAGE
        // Create a Constraints object that defines when the task should run
        Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build();

        // Passing data to the worker class
        Data.Builder uploadBuilder = new Data.Builder();
        uploadBuilder.putString("image_uri", placeImageUri.toString());
        uploadBuilder.putString("image_pushkey", placeKey);
        Data ImageUriInputData = uploadBuilder.build();

        // ...then create a OneTimeWorkRequest that uses those constraints
        OneTimeWorkRequest uploadWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                .Builder(UploadImageWorker.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(ImageUriInputData)
                .build();

        OneTimeWorkRequest downloadWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                .Builder(DownloadImageUrlWorker.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build();

        // Converting placeObject into Map
        Data.Builder uploadPlaceBuilder = new Data.Builder();
        Map<String, Object> placeMap = convertPlaceObjectIntoMap();
        uploadPlaceBuilder.putAll(placeMap);
        Data placeInfoInputData = uploadPlaceBuilder.build();

        OneTimeWorkRequest uploadPlaceWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest
                .Builder(UploadPlaceWorker.class)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(placeInfoInputData)
                .build();

        // Execute and Manage the background service
        WorkManager workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(getActivity());
        workManager.beginWith(uploadWorkRequest)
                .then(downloadWorkRequest)
                .then(uploadPlaceWorkRequest)
                .enqueue();
    }
```

Below are the `Worker` classes:

```
public class UploadImageWorker extends Worker {

    public UploadImageWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        String imageUriInput = getInputData().getString("image_uri");
        String imagePushKey = getInputData().getString("image_pushkey");

        final Result[] result = {Result.retry()};
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        StorageReference storageRef = DatabaseRouter.getPlaceStorageRef(imagePushKey).child(imagePushKey+".jpg");
        storageRef.putFile(Uri.parse(imageUriInput)).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    result[0] = Result.success(getInputData());
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: image NOT uploaded - RETRYING");
                    result[0] = Result.retry();
                }
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result[0];
    }
}

public class DownloadImageUrlWorker extends Worker {

    public DownloadImageUrlWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        String imageUriInput = getInputData().getString("image_uri");
        String imagePushKey = getInputData().getString("image_pushkey");

        final Result[] result = {Result.retry()};
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        StorageReference storageRef = DatabaseRouter.getPlaceStorageRef(imagePushKey).child(imagePushKey+".jpg");
        storageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                String imageUrl = uri.toString();

                Data.Builder outputBuilder = new Data.Builder();
                outputBuilder.putString("image_url", imageUrl);
                outputBuilder.putString("image_pushkey", imagePushKey);
                Data outputData = outputBuilder.build();
                result[0] = Result.success(outputData);

                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: imageUrl NOT downloaded - RETRYING");
                result[0] = Result.retry();
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });



        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result[0];
    }
}

public class UploadPlaceWorker extends Worker {

    public UploadPlaceWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        String imageUrl = getInputData().getString("image_url");
        String imagePushKey = getInputData().getString("image_pushkey");

        Map<String, Object> placeObject = getInputData().getKeyValueMap();

        PlaceModel placeModel = convertMapIntoPlaceObject(placeObject, imageUrl, imagePushKey);

        final Result[] result = {Result.retry()};
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        DocumentReference docRef = DatabaseRouter.getPlaceCollectionRef().document(imagePushKey);
        docRef.set(placeModel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    result[0] = Result.success();
                } else {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onComplete: place NOT uploaded - RETRYING");
                    result[0] = Result.retry();
                }
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result[0];
    }

    private PlaceModel convertMapIntoPlaceObject(Map<String, Object> placeMap, String imageUrl, String placeKey) {
        PlaceModel place = new PlaceModel();
        place.setAddress(placeMap.get("a").toString());
        place.setCity(placeMap.get("b").toString());
        place.setCountry(placeMap.get("c").toString());
        place.setDistrict(placeMap.get("d").toString());
        place.setG(placeMap.get("e").toString());
        place.setId(placeMap.get("f").toString());
        place.setImage(imageUrl);
        place.setKey(placeKey);
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((Double) placeMap.get("h"), (Double) placeMap.get("i"));
        place.setL(geoPoint);
        place.setDescription(placeMap.get("j").toString());

        return place;
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help!